# withForm not passing Model data to gsp using Grails 2.2.4

Tags: grails

I am trying to use withForm in Grails 2.2.4
 I have added useToken='true'  to a form on an existing gsp file.

However, when I wrap the associated controller method with a withForm { ... }.invalidToken{ response.status = 405}  I get internal server errors because the gsp generation fails as none of the attributes from the model are received.

To show this,  I have replaced the real render code with some simple statements that print out the values for the passed in model attributes.

If I do not use the withForm wrapper, then all works well.  But as soon as the withForm is wrapped around the content, the model information no longer comes through.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?  Should the model be placed below the withForm syntax?

Controller code:

```
def browse () {
 //     withForm {
    def filter = null       
    def challenges = []
    def oimlChallenges = []
    def breadCrumbs
    def total
    def model = SystemUtil.baseModel(request)
    def Boolean enablePartnerChallenge
    def currentUser = springSecurityService?.currentUser
    def source = params.source ?: 'innocentive'
    model += [enablePartnerChallenge: enablePartnerChallenge, max: params.max ?: 10,]
    filter = ChallengeFilter.build(params, sswcEnabled())
    model += [challenges: challenges,
                filter: filter, total: total, sort: 'postedDate',
                currentOffset: params.offset, source: source,
                searchTerm: params.searchTerm,
                userFilter: userFilter()]

    render(view: 'browse', model: model)
//      }.invalidToken{ response.status = 405}
 }
```

gsp code:

```
<body>
  <g:render template="/panels/headerUX"
    model="[selectedMenu: 'Challenge Center']" />
  <div class="body-container">
    <div class="container">
        <g:form name='filterForm' action="browse" id='filterForm' 
             method="post" useToken="true">

         browse.gsp values:
         ${source.toString()}
         ${pavilionId.toString()}
         ${enablePartnerChallenge}
         ${challengeListing.toString()}
         ${pavilionTitle}


 <%--               <g:render template='browseTabsRefresh' model="${[source: source, pavilionId: pavilionId, enablePartnerChallenge: enablePartnerChallenge, challengeListing: challengeListing, pavilionTitle: pavilionTitle]}" />--%>
 <%--               <g:render template="newFilterPanel" model="${model}" />--%>
 <%--               <div id="challengeListDiv">--%>
 <%--                   <g:render template='challengeListRefresh'--%>
 <%--                       model="${[challenges:challenges, filter:filter, userFilter: userFilter, challengeListing:challengeListing]}" />--%>
 <%--               </div>--%>

        </g:form>
    </div>
</div>

<g:render template="/panels/footerUX" />
```

The printed results without withForm:
browse.gsp values: innocentive null null

The printed results using withForm:
browse.gsp values: null null null

Notice that the original contained the value 'innocentive' and it is now coming in as null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that GSP code shown for browse.gsp?  It appears as though you are accessing your `browse` method without actually submitting your form.  Unless you submit the form, only the `invalidToken` part will execute and it will try to render your browse.gsp afterward (as you are only changing the HTTP response code, but not redirecting or rendering text or a different .gsp).

To verify, replace your `invalidToken` block with something like the following so it doesn't try and render the .gsp

```
}.invalidToken{ 
            render(status: 405, text: "Invalid Token")
}
```

For your real implementation, you'll want to redirect to an error page or something similar.

Comment: Yes, the problem was the mismatch between the form and the method.  I had randomly picked a form to do my first update on. Unfortunately the one I picked behaves unusually and the method processes with or without form data.   Since it worked, it didn't occur to me that it would be a problem.  When I updated a 'standard' form that followed conventions, the withForm worked fine. Thanks for such a clear explanation!